# How to bind this source variable to an existing textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

Good Day! I recently found this on the Microsoft site.

```
// Create the list to use as the custom source. 
            var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            source.AddRange(new string[]
                    {
                        "January",
                        "February",
                        "March",
                        "April",
                        "May",
                        "June",
                        "July",
                        "August",
                        "September",
                        "October",
                        "November",
                        "December"
                    });


            // Create and initialize the text box.
            var textBox = new TextBox
            {
                AutoCompleteCustomSource = source,
                AutoCompleteMode =
                    AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
                AutoCompleteSource =
                    AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
                Location = new Point(20, 20),
                Width = ClientRectangle.Width - 40,
                Visible = true
            };

            // Add the text box to the form.
            Controls.Add(textBox);
```

What it does is it creates a collection of strings and a new Textbox. Im just wondering if there's a way to bind this source to an existing Textbox instead of creating a new one. I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
            txtTo.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
            txtTo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            txtTo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Comment: It should work. Where did you put your code? in Form_Load?

Comment: What happens upon running your code? Does an exception occur? In any case, you can place your code in the constructor or in the OnLoad event, just that, make sure `InitializeComponent();` is called first before your code since that will initialize your `TextBox` control.

Comment: Try the line `txtTo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource` before the `CustomSource` and `CompleteMode`

Comment: @rjs123431 Yes, I put it in Form_Load event.

Comment: @MichaelBalser the code works. My question is if I can bind the source variable to an existing textbox instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @JoshTest `I tried the following code but it doesn't work.`
This was what you said, that it **doesn't** work. I tried to do what you have described (existing TextBox) and it completely works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        source.AddRange(new string[]
                {
                    "January",
                    "February",
                    "March",
                    "April",
                    "May",
                    "June",
                    "July",
                    "August",
                    "September",
                    "October",
                    "November",
                    "December"
                });

        txtTo.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
        txtTo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        txtTo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

    }
```